# Use pug variable in client js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am able to receive the variable from node js to pug, the same when I console it inside inline script I am able to print the data. But how to pass on the variable to external client js file included in pug file

Node js :

```
res.render(home, {
  title: "home page",
  userId: id 
})
```

Pug:

```
body
  -var newId = userId;
script.
  var jsNewId = #{newId}
  console.log("jsNewId",jsNewId)
```

this console.log prints the expected newid value. I wanted to send the same value to js file that is included in pug file footer:

```
script(src="js/client.js type="text/javascript)
```

client.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var jsNewId = #{newId}  //cannot use this syntax 
   })
```

How to get the pug variable in client js file

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](https://riptutorial.com/pug/example/29560/value-interpolation-in-javascript-code), the best way to do this would be to make it a global variable.

Your Node js should stay the same. The Pug file would look like this:

```
body
  // insert content here
  script.
    var newId = #{newId}
    console.log("jsNewId", newId)
```

Note: If `newId` is a string, then you would have to wrap it in quotation marks, like this:

```
script.
  var newId = "#{newId}"
  console.log("jsNewId", newId)
```

Then, you can call

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      var jsNewId = newId  // OK because newId is global
   })
```

As a final note, if your variable was a Javascript object, you would need the following syntax:

```
script.
  var user = !{JSON.stringify(user)};
```

`!` tells pug to keep the output unbuffered.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a javascript variable declared in an inline `script` tag from within an external javascript file, you'll need to either make it a [global variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable) (not recommended), or use something like [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

Within your Pug file (be sure to indent your `script` tag inside the `body`)

```
body
  - let newId = userId
  script.
    let jsNewId = #{newId}
    localStorage.setItem('jsNewId', jsNewId)
```

Then in your client.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let jsNewId = localStorage.getItem('jsNewId')
})
```

It would be good to include your client.js file as the last item in the `body` to be sure `jsNewId` exists in local storage before it tries to get it.

Comment: It also looks like you're missing a closing `"` where you include the client.js file within Pug.